# Validating inputs that share the same name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using a method as explained here: http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/unchecked-checkbox-values/ to get a value even if the checkbox is left unchecked, I won't go into details about why I need this but it's a necessity. That being said..

All this wonderful method is part of an abstraction layer for form that I've written myself, I have a couple of checkboxes that I whish to get validated by jquery validate, the problem is that the html is like this:

```
<input class="" type="hidden" value="0" name="check[legal]">
<input id="legal" class="required" type="checkbox" name="check[legal]" value="1">
```

What happens is that jquery validate validates the first input of the two (since they have both the same name.
I understand that I can simply remove the first one and be done with it, I just want to know if there is any way to validate the second checkbox leaving everything as it is (I can see two roads here: 1) validate from the id of the input 2) exclude hidden elements from validation, even if I think that that way it will avoid even the second one for having the same name..)

Comment: Why do they have to have the same name?  Are they part of the same group of checkboxes?  If so, they get validated together.  If not, assign them different names.  This seems simple, so what am I missing?

Comment: You misse the article I posted just to avoid this question. They share the same name so that if the second one (the visible one) doesn't get checked I get 0 instead of nothing in the $_POST array.

Comment: Use JavaScript to copy the value of the checkbox into a different hidden field and always send/use that one instead.  Just because something is part of the post array, does not mean you have to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the direct answer to your question is that you can define a custom validate method as [shown in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/TKA4G/1/). Here is the critical code:

```
$.validator.methods.checkLegal = function(value, element) {
    return $('input[type=checkbox][name="check[legal]"]').attr('checked');
}

$('form').validate({
    rules: { "check[legal]": {checkLegal: true} },
    messages: { "check[legal]": "You must check the box" },
});
```

However, your fields don't need to have the same name to use the principle described in the link you provided. In fact, it will simplify things greatly if you don't. It is also unclear why you need braces in the variable names if this is not a checkbox list.

That said, [here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/JGsVp/1/) that does not use the same names, stores the hidden value, and validates the visible checkbox. The replacement for the above being:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: { "check[legal]": "required" },
    });

    $('#legal').click(function(e) {
        $('#legalHidden').val($(this).attr('checked') ? 1 : 0);
    });

});
```

On the server, you would simply reference check[legalhidden] and not bother with check[legal]. On the client, all validation is done on check[legal] and the value is copied into the legalhidden var each time it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just so you know, the braces in the variable names are there to aid the processing of the POST array, for example dumping the checks after validation unset($_POST['check']).